# Detecting almost straight lines

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, hough-transform

How to detect almost straight lines in an image using MATLAB? Hough Transform not able to detect the lines properly, as lines are not exactly smooth. And, is there any way to detect all the rectangles in the image or thick lines (assume same color rectangle as a thick line)??
 Here is the image [image]

Comment: There is such a Thing as a Radon transform for circles, so maybe there is a hybrid for arc segments.  If your line is wobbly, maybe you can downsample it until it is effectively straight.

Comment: so just smooth the image and use Hough Transform.... Seriously, show the image you are talking about.

Comment: @natan, @ Adrian Ratnapala; check updated question?

Comment: Could you not use a simple edge detector algorithm to detect where the transitions between the different shapes are? Given the structure of the image that would make the most sense to me.
Although detecting the rectangles after that probably isn't going to be trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply canny edge detector to the image and do a labeling and you'll detect most of the rectangles.

rgb : the image

edges = edge(rgb2gray(rgb), 'canny');

labels = label2rgb(bwlabel(edges, 8));

figure, imshow(edges)

figure, imshow(labels)